# I have named him/he who shall not be named?

Tags: direct-objects

I have named him/he who shall not be named. Which of these is correct? I think it should be "him" because "him" is a direct object in this context. In this context, "him/he who shall not be named" is not a proper noun.

Comment: I've seen this type of question popping up on various forums recently. (Personal pronoun modified by a relative clause.) There might be one or two threads here on this forum. . . .

Comment: I am new to English SE. I am simply looking for an answer to my question, if you know of somewhere else where I can find one, I would be happy to look there... I am not sure exactly what you are trying to get at. @F.E.

Comment: Someone might provide a link to one of those threads.

Comment: As to which one to use, it probably depends on the context and on the register.

Comment: What do you mean by the "register"? Also, I think all the context is in the sentence itself. There is a person who should not be named, and I have named him.

Comment: Oh, there's a 3rd possibility: The "I" has given someone the name of *"who shall not be named"*! :)

Comment: This is one of those cases (pun intended) where the fact that English pronoun case are in the process of being functionally redistributed actually ruins something. No matter which you choose, it will sound wrong to some people—and it will probably sound wrong to many in _both_ versions. I'd suggest wriggling your way around it and avoiding the pronoun altogether: “I have named the one who must not be named”.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not looking to write a sentence with the same meaning as this one, I am trying to determine which of the two possible sentence structures that I described in my question statement functions better. That being said, I would probably try to avoid sentences structured in this manner in my own writing.

Comment: This has already been addressed, for instance [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical/81369#81369). (See _Let him who is without sin cast the first stone._ /

* _Let he who is without sin cast the first stone_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I cannot tell what the answer to my question is given that one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It would be very helpful if you could tell me what the answer to my question is, as I cannot understand what it is from the answer that you linked me to.

Comment: Shoe's answer repeats the previous one.

Comment: You should edit your question by entering two separate  sentences/phrases. The way it is now just leads to confusion and tiresome discussion. Your use of the slash is confusing.

Answer (score 4):

I this case, I believe "He Who Shall Not Be Named" is a set phrase, functioning a bit like proper name in this context. So you won't change that first word of it. Just like you won't change "I have named [He-Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He-Man)" to "I have named Him-Man" - the "He" is part of the object.

Comment: In this case, please assume that "He Who Shall Not Be Named" is not a proper noun. Does that change the answer?

Comment: @okarin, it is not a proper noun as such, but (especially since the Harry Potter books), it is so much a set phrase that many will be loath to change it in any way.

Comment: It's actually 'He Who Must Not Be Named' in the Harry Potter books, and Rowling uses it as a proper noun (which is HER prerogative), capitalising it and not changing case where conventional grammar would otherwise require it. Interestingly, therefore, saying 'He Who Must Not Be Named' _is_ actually naming Voldemort.

Comment: @okarin - That's an important detail that should be included as part of your question, not buried in a comment beneath an answer. I'm glad you took the time to add it.

Comment: @Edwin: In the Harry Potter books, the meaning is actually not "He Who Must Not Be Given a Name" but "He Whose True Name Must Not Be Spoken". See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/name), second definition of name: *to say the name of (someone or something).*

Comment: @Peter: I'm saying that **uttering** the words 'He Who Must Not Be Named' is equivalent to saying 'Voldemort', just as uttering 'Father Christmas' is equivalent to uttering 'Santa Claus'. Rowling has conferred proper noun status on the six-word lexeme. cf 'Her Indoors' and 'She Who Must Be Obeyed'. Of course, we could debate the meaning of 'true names' (Tom Riddle?), but nicknames qualify as names.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be *I have named **him** who shall not be named*. *Him* is the direct object of the verb in the main clause. The relative clause starting with *who* identifies the *him* but does not influence its (object) case.

Here is similar construction:

> She made him who he is today. **

Note: You can use *he* in the main clause if *he* is the complement rather than the object of the verb:

> It was he who told me.

Admittedly, this is formal English and I suspect most people (in the UK at least) would say:

> It was him who told me.

---

**Edited: See the comment from and to Edwin Ashworth below.

Comment: Would people in the U.S. say something different?

Comment: I don't quite get this. In 'It was he who told me', 'he' seems to me to be the object. If not, what is the object of the verb 'was'? Hence, my thought is that 'It was him who told me' is correct.

Comment: @okarin, I wanted to be cautious in my assertion about this particular usage, being exposed mainly to BE English. Maybe someone can link to some evidence confirming or disconfirming it. As an aside, the use of _shall_ and _he who shall not be named_ give the sentence an archaic, religious quality. If you are writing in such a context, you may wish to retain the _he_.

Comment: @WS2, ‘to be’ is a linking verb: it cannot take an object. It takes a predicate instead, which is (traditionally, and still at least optionally in current English) the same case as its subject. This is very clear in languages that have ‘proper’ case systems, but less so in English, where the logic behind the cases has been changing and breaking down over the past few centuries.

Comment: @WS2. Only transitive verbs such as _make, see, hit_, etc. can have direct objects. _To be_ is an intransitive verb. In colloquial contexts I doubt that many people would answer the question _Who told you?_ with _It was he!_, but some might be a little hesitant to use the object pronoun in such statements in very formal contexts.

Comment: _I have named him who shall not be named_ and _She made him who he is today_ are very different structures; 'who shall not be named' is a relative clause whereas 'who he is today' is a reduced object complement ('the man (who) he is today').

Comment: For *was*, the rules are different.

Comment: @Edwin, You are right. It was not a good example. I did concoct in my head a few sentences that were exactly parallel, but they  seemed unnatural: e.g. _I saw him who shall not be approached. I liked him who was disliked by everyone else_, etc, so I rejected them in favour of the construction above. I have edited to refer to your comment.

Comment: I think your conclusion is correct, but unfortunately all your examples are irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter, could you expand on your comment about the rules being different for was? As to my three examples, the first was not well-chosen as explained above, but the second was intended to illustrate when _he_ in the main clause could be the right choice, so not totally irrelevant.

Comment: The traditional rules for the verb *to be* is that it takes a complement, in the nominative case, rather than an object, in the objective case. Since this is exactly what you said, ignore my earlier comment.

Comment: @Peter Shor So are we saying that when I knock at my neighbour's door and he cries 'Who's there?', I must call 'It is I', not 'It is me'?   The verb 'to be' certainly doesn't work like that in French. 'L'état, c'est moi'.

Comment: @WS2: traditionally, you were indeed supposed to say "it is I", and that's what grammatical prescriptivists tell you to say. Nowadays, most people actually would say "it's me".

Comment: So is it fair to say, then, that as a general rule, if a relative clause modifies a pronoun (in particular, one with different forms for different cases), that the case of the pronoun is dependent upon its role in the main clause, and not its role in the relative clause?

Comment: (And, can you reference some authority on this?)

Comment: @Keith B: On page 231 of the Google Books copy of (old) Fowler is a list of examples of the error of using _he_ where _him_ [etc] is required. Fowler’s first example of the mistake is “The bell will always be rung by he who has the longest purse & the strongest arm.” I'd add 'Do not follow he who breaks the law.' Sadly, Fowler didn't justify his pronouncement, but was a highly respected grammarian.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: That works. I've been doing it wrong this whole time! While googling that phrase, I also came upon [this](http://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2009/02/19/let-her-who-is-without-error/) blog post, which, while not an authority, I think does a good job of explaining the rule and why.

Comment: @Keith B: The 'Let P (who . . .) V+' construction is arguably a little different. The 'Do not follow P who V+' construction ('follow' could be other sensibly chosen verbs, such as envy, believe, tolerate in this example alone, of course) is, I'd say, the one where there is the greatest temptation to wrongly use the objective case where the pronoun has one. I'd certainly rephrase 'Do not follow me who break the law' though.

Answer (score 2):

I have named (him/he) (who) shall not be named. The choices are:

*I have named him whom shall not be named*. and *I have named he who shall not be named.*

Substituting a different pair;

I have killed (them/those who(m) will not be killed, would become

*I have killed them whom will not be killed*. or *I have killed those who will not be killed.*

I have never seen this construction: them whom will not be killed, nor *those whom will not be killed.*  **I cannot support this usage.**

It seems to be an illogical construction. I think the *who* complicates the phrase, as well as the implication that you've accomplished the linguistic impossibility.

I would argue that (he-who-shall-not-be-named) is your direct object.

I have named **he** who shall not be named. (acceptable)

However, as I cannot cite sources, I hope a linguist will hop in on this.

Comment: I understand the reasoning you are supplying, but I don't see an answer. Are you saying *I have named **he** who shall not be named* or *I have named **him** who shall be named*?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, but if I understand you correctly, I'm afraid it's not correct. “I have named him whom shall not be named” is quite ungrammatical. “I have named he who shall not be named” is acceptable to most, but would fail with prescriptionists.

Comment: Fowler (see the above link) labels constructions such as 'I have named he who shall not be named' ungrammatical.

Comment: @Susan, I see what you’re saying now—I’ve un-downvoted. :-)

Comment: It should clearly not be *whom*, as the rule is: if *who(m)* fills the role of both subject and object, use *who*. But *him* is only an object here, so I think it should be *"him who shall not be named"*.

Comment: @Susan: Upon reconsideration, my rule doesn't apply here: *him* is the object of the main clause, and *who* is the subject of the relative clause, so *him who* is correct.

Comment: There's the 'rule' [here](http://sesquiotic.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/i-must-disagree-with-whoever-wrote-that/), but no authority or logical justification.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a bit of a set phrase, I would decline it (here, decline meaning change the word according to the case in which it is used -- rather than refuse).

Thus, I would say *I have named him who shall not be named*.

Seeing @AvnerShahar-Kashtan has given the opposite answer, I wonder if it depends on where one learned to speak English or how one speaks English. My English is American English, and I tend to maintain the proper uses of subjunctives and to decline foreign words as they decline in their own languages as best I can when using them in English (i.e. alumni for the plural of alumnus and alumnae for the feminine plural, etc.).

Comment: Surely you wouldn't say: "I've just seen _Him-Man_ at the cinema"? If _He who must not be named_ / _He Who Must Not Be Named_ / _He who shall not be named_ is a multi-word proper noun, it is caseless. If it is considered to be a post-modified personal pronoun, it should be written in the appropriate case.

Comment: *He-Man* is unequivocally a proper name. I consider *he who must not be named* to be an idiom and thus subject to conjugation.

Comment: But J K Rowling [doesn't](http://q-pheevr.livejournal.com/43408.html), [at least in her books](http://www.dummies.com/Section/Choosing-to-Use-Who-and-Whom.id-410094.html): <<. . . treat "[He Who Must Not Be Named]" as a single entity . . . in Harry Potter. Wizards always refer to Voldemort as He Who Must Not Be Named. They wouldn't say "Death Eaters pledge allegiance to Him Who Must Not Be Named." He who must not be named is taken as a single entity, as a name itself. As such, the pronoun doesn't change.>> As with Lloyds and Lloyd's (and Waterstones Bookshops), I'd say it's her call.

Comment: I haven't read those books, but I've known the idiom... so I'm not sure how it becomes the call of an author who uses an already existing idiom in a particular way. If the asker is referring to *Harry Potter* then surely he should copy the original author's intent.

Comment: So should we not capitalise Batman because the word was pressed into a different usage from the original military one? I suspect more people have heard of J K Rowling than Bill Finger. I'd say that both 'batman' and 'Batman' are allowable terms, but I've never come across 'Batmen'.

Comment: If you are referring to Batman, the comic owned by DC, then  most definitely capitalize. If you are referring  to any of a number of other batmen, then don't. Even DC Comics pluralized "Batmen" on one occassion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batmen_of_All_Nations.

The rule is simple: obviously if you are just using someone else's idea follow their construction rules. If the idea is more generic that you are using, use the rules that apply to that construction. Most idioms are treated grammatically when used.

Comment: But the only instances of "He who must not be named" I can discover after a reasonable amount of surfing are Rowling-related. [Apparently](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/voldemort.html), she got the idea (though not the actual form of the expression) from two 1950s London gangsters, the mere mention of whose name could result in swift punishment. So it seems to be her idea / coinage, not a quote. So, by your own rules, following her practice, we see that "He who must not be named" doesn't have case.

Comment: Well maybe you should surf differently. Googling he who must not be named -voldemort -potter yields a boatload of unrelated uses. I cite a few for your ease: http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20131224/opinion/He-who-must-not-be-named.500259#.Us6miNJs3zY , http://www.threadsuk.com/god-he-who-must-not-be-named/ , http://www.motherjones.com/mixed-media/2013/05/m-night-shyamalan-after-earth-marketing ,

my logic is that if he means harry potter (which we don't know) then by all means, don't decline it. If not, decline it.

Comment: So you would say that 'Some are born great, some achieve greatness, and some have greatness thrust upon them' need not be Shakespeare-related? I'd say that all the examples you give are very probably – in fact almost certainly – unattributed references to Rowling's proper noun. Try to find any examples that pre-date her publications; _that_ would be convincing evidence. Perhaps you should analyse differently. Oh, and _Harry Potter_ is definitely a proper noun and capitalised (unless one is referring to a different entity, which obviously you aren't).

Comment: You also say: 'I consider _he who must not be named_ to be an idiom' / 'a bit of a set phrase'. I can find it in no dictionary of idioms, but it is easily found (capitalised) as the obvious Rowling version in other reference works. I'm totally in agreement with you that if it's not a multi-word proper noun, it should be declined where necessary – but if these are all quotes (whether attributed or not) from a coining by Rowling, they should faithfully reproduce her original.

Answer (score -1):

Whom shall I say is calling?  Whom is the indirect object, the dative case.  I shall give this to whom?
I found the right rule but didn't apply it right.  He who must not be named: "he" is the direct object of "named".  So neither "him" nor "whom" can go here.

Comment: This is nearby (about case of a question word) but doesn't address the OP's actual question. Can you update this to talk about a pronoun's case when it is ambiguously also part of a relative clause?

Comment: I just edited my remark.  I think those rules are clear and easy, and "name" is not an exception: viz, "I named him 'George', "George" is the direct object, "him" is the indirect object, and when this sentence is made into a relative/adjectival clause, that all remains intact.  The ambiguity would be, as stated by others here, if the entire phrase becomes a name itself, a proper name, as it were.  Then "who" remains unaffected by how this proper name is used in a sentence.

Comment: Two hours later I think I have this figured out.  The phrase uses "name" to mean "be referred to by name", not "given a name".  You refer to someone by name as the indirect object: him or her.