# How to conjugate verb in relative clause where case changes?

Tags: relative-clauses, conjugation

I'm not sure how the following sentence should be built:

"She gives a blanket to me, who (am/is/?) cold"

I can't come up with anything that *sounds* right, and I'm not certain there *is* a right. Can this be done in English? Obviously in this example sentence, it should be restructured to sound normal, but I'm looking for a rule on this structure.

Comment: You might take a look at this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28662/18655

Comment: Undoubtedly, the historical answer is "who am". I am inclined to the view that modern English _has no rule_ for this. I don't doubt that you can find pundits telling you what you should say, but to me neither choice sounds right. The puzzling thing is that this implies that the construction is ungrammatical, but _only_ with the word "me", not with any other pronoun.

Comment: A bare 'She gives a blanket to me' sounds odd enough. The whole sentence sounds positively archaic. 'I was cold, so she gave me a blanket' sounds like something a normal person might say.

Comment: @Colin: I don't want to come across as a "pundit", but surely the "lesser of two evils" is *"...to I, who am cold."* ?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: descriptively, you may be right. It's not what I would say (if I had to, I'd go with _to me, who is cold_) but I can quite imagine, for example, people having unconsciously internalised a rule that says "if in doubt, use 'I'". But I don't think you risk being a pundit: they would all roundly lambast you for that "I".

Comment: @Colin: Both versions sound so awkward to me I don't think my inner grammarian's opinion is worth a light on this one. But I had to look into it, and there's no denying that the pundits are winning re the **I / me** issue (with all those who insist on trying to use the basic construction here at all, who I think are a vanishing minority today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment to the question notwithstanding, it seems that when faced with this difficult choice, the majority have gone with the **me + am** version...

> *[Be a guide to me who am empty of every good work.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22be%20a%20guide%20to%20me%20who%20am%20empty%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>
>    [You alone, O Jesus, are everything to me who am all yours.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22be%20a%20guide%20to%20me%20who%20am%20empty%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22to%20me%20who%20am%22%20-%22who%20am%20empty%22&tbm=bks)
>
>    [Come then to me, who am a midwife](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Come%20then%20to%20me,%20who%20am%20a%20midwife%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)*
>    etc., etc,...

There are at least dozens, if not hundreds of similar forms in Google Books. Admittedly, most of them are *old* (and of course, there's no way of measuring the vastly greater number of times writers have simply rephrased to avoid the problem). But it's a "vote of confidence" of sorts.

Per @Colin's comments above, I don't think there's any doubt that *strictly speaking*, there is no other grammatically valid alternative. But obviously no-one much likes it, so we usually rephrase.

---

Since I hold him in such high regard, I must just cite [Daniel Defoe's 1719 Robinson Crusoe](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22justice%20to%20me%20who%20was%20a%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)...

> *in common justice **to me, who was** a considerable owner in the ship, the could not turn me as it were out of my own house.*

...to show that **me** has to be right. It just works better with a past rather than present tense verb.

Comment: I am shocked, simply shocked, that you answered this question when JLG made clear that this is a duplicate. Have you no concern about the sanctity of this site? ;-) [I hate emoticoms!]

Comment: Hoist by own petard! Okay, I'll closevote. @JLG - why on earth did you say *"You might take a look at this"* rather than closevoting? Or at least saying something a bit clearer that might have made me actually follow the link before answering?

Comment: @bib: I *have concern **for*** the sanctity of the site. Doubtless only Americans would *have concern **about*** such a thing. But us Brits would certainly *express **concerns about*** the prospect of the site getting bogged down in such pettifogging pedantry! :)