# Verb agreement in “It is you who has/have come”

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, copular-verbs, clefts, grammatical-person

Today I was playing the video game *Assassin’s Creed Syndicate* on my PC. In a mission where the player whose name is Evie Frye meets a guy, the guy says I thought Jacob was coming but  that

> I am glad that it is you who **have** come.

After hearing this, I got a little bit confused because  I would have used *has* instead. So native English speakers, could you please tell me which verb is suitable to use here?

Comment: If ‘you’ is singular, then it is ‘has’ not ‘have’.

Comment: @cloudsafe: that's not the way it traditionally worked (although the usage is slowly drifting away from the traditionally correct grammar). [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+I+who+have%2C+it+is+i+who+has%2C+it+is+you+who+have%2C+it+is+you+who+has&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20I%20who%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20you%20who%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20you%20who%20has%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @PeterShor Indeed, for although “it is I who am” isn’t particularly common, “it is I who is” does not even occur. Therefore it must agree with the person preceding *who*, which with *you* is always plural agreement.

Comment: Duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68919  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/174628 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28662 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/68919 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/17636 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57954 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/304258 and many more.