# Can "those" be used in "those good at writing" or "those who ..."?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Can "those" be used in "those good at writing" or "those who ..." to refer to a group of people shared the same attribute described by the phrase after "those"?

If it is possible (since I have found lots of examples with Google), is "those" here a noun?

Comment: Yes, “those” can be used this way. “Those good at writing” becomes a [noun phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase). Here’s a famous list that uses this construction: _[Borges’ Animals](http://www.multicians.org/thvv/borges-animals.html)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule *who + BE* and *which + BE* can be omitted from so-called restrictive relative clauses.

- Those who are happy with the situation ...
- Those happy with the situation ...
- Those who are thinking of leaving ....
- Those thinking of leaving ...
- Those who are regularly forgotten ...
- Those regularly for gotten ...
- These who have been dropped ...
- Those dropped ...

In the examples above we see the relative pronoun *who* omitted from sentences with *BE*: as the only verb; as part of the present continuous; as part of a passive construction, and as part of a present perfect passive construction.

Now whether the examples without a relative pronoun are actually relative clauses is a matter of some debate. Some people would regard them as post-modifying adjective/participle clauses. However, this nonetheless effectively boils down to the fact that you can always omit *who/which* and *BE* from the comparable relative clauses.

*Those*, when used on its own like this, is classified as a pronoun. Many modern grammars treat pronouns as a subset of the Noun category. So in this sense it is a noun. *Those* with a following noun, however, is usually classified as a determiner. So in the following it would be classified as a determiner:

- Those people who are satisfied with the situation ...

This of course is a rather silly situation where we have to treat the same word with ostensibly the same meaning and the same grammar as a different word just depending on what word follows it. Some forward thinking modern grammarians see *those* as the same kind of word in both instances.

I have occasionally seen it written that pronouns cannot serve as antecedents for relative clauses. However, this only ever really applies to accusative case pronouns: *me, him, her, us, them*. Even then this is more a case of awkwardness or style, perhaps, rather than ungrammaticality:

- # May heaven forgive him who steals for his children. (debatable grammaticality)

Notice, though, that this does not apply to *those* - which does not inflect for case (and could be argued, therefore, to not be accusative).

Comment: See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28662/8019).

Comment: @TimLymington Yes, excellent question and some interesting answers!

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration! A misspelling by the way: "this is moe a case of awkwardness" => "this is more a case of awkwardness".

Answer (score 2):

In this case those is a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

*Who are* can be safely omitted. It is understood. The sentence is still grammatical even if we drop it.