# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "Isn't it only you who have that book?"

Tags: relative-clauses, questions, question-tags, clefts

Instead of saying:

> 1. "It's only you who have that book, isn't it?"

can we say,

> 2. "Isn't it only you who have that book?"

Comment: I think it's technically correct, but awkward.

Comment: Cross-posted to ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38956/is-this-sentence-grammatically-correct-isnt-it-only-you-who-have-that-book

Answer (score 3):

You could. However, both of those variants sound rather stiff and old-fashioned to my ear. Today, a more conversational wording would be "It's only you that has that book, isn't it?"

Comment: Thank you. However, can we use "has" as the verb? I mean, the verb doesn't agree with the subject "you", does it?

Comment: No, in terms of formal grammar it doesn't agree. However, in an informal conversational context, the alternative wording I supplied is perfectly acceptable. I'd go so far as to say that to use *have* there would actually strike a false note.

Comment: It's perfectly fine and it's formal. _Have_ would be incorrect. This is a cleft sentence and _you_ is not the subject; it's the predicate noun.

Comment: I would probably say "You're the only one who has that book, aren't you?"

Comment: We have a [dedicated question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical) for that. Any follow-up discussion not related to the question at hand should be taken there.