# A relative pronoun acting as both object and subject?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns

> I don't want to do anything you think might be good for me.
>
> This is something he said was good for me.

In the first sentence, the relative pronoun between ***anything*** and ***you think*** is omitted as it is an object. But, my concern is, ***might be good for me*** needs a relative pronoun to be its subject, and there's no relative pronoun in the sentence. Why? Is there any grammar rule that can explain this? The same question goes for the second sentence.

My theory is, that the omitted relative pronoun between ***anything*** and ***you think*** also acts as the subject of ***might be good for me*** even though it is omitted. But still, I don't know if this is grammatical and I've never seen any explanation about this type of construction in my grammar books.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical): "Let him/he who is without sin cast the first stone. The prescriptive 'over-rule' is that he/him (who is without sin), which links the letting and the casting the first stone, has its case governed by the letting (ie is in the objective) rather than by the casting the first stone. But ... Google stats indicate the 'incorrect' choice occurs three times as often as the 'correct'. ..."

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that the relative pronoun is in a nested clause, rather than in the 'topmost' relative clause. That is why it is difficult to analyse, and why it might behave in a way that is slightly different from what one may be used to.

A basic relative clause:

> This is the man **whom** I saw.

Main clause: *this is the man*

Relative clause: ***whom** I saw*

*Whom* is the object of *saw* in the relative clause. In the main clause, the relative clause is no full constituent (it doesn't fulfil a role in the main clause except as an attribute to *man*).

If you extract the relative clause from the main clause and turn it into a second main clause, you get this:

> This is the man. I saw **him**.

The relative pronoun is replaced with a personal pronoun. In a normal main clause, the object would come after the verb, as here; but, in a relative clause, the relative pronoun is normally moved to the beginning of the relative clause. That is why we had *the man whom...* in the original example. Without this move, which is standard in (most? all?) Indo-European languages, it would be difficult to see where the relative clause begins, which in turn makes a sentence harder to parse.

Now a nested example, but let's begin with two main clauses:

> I saw the man. I think **he** was mad.

The pronoun *he* refers back to a constituent in the first clause (*man*), so that is what we will replace with *that/who*. Notice that *he* is the subject of the subordinate clause *he was mad*; this clause is subordinate to *I think* (it is nested within it).

> *<s>I saw the man I think **who** was mad.</s>

We have replaced the subject *he* with a relative pronoun *who*. But this doesn't sound right: we want the relative pronoun to move to the beginning of the entire clause that used to be the second main clause (but is now the upper relative clause). So we move *who*:

> I saw the man **who** I think was mad.

So the relative pronoun is still subject, but it was moved out of the inner clause.

---

Now on to your examples.

> I don't want to do anything you think might be good for me.

I can split this into two main clauses (there will be a slight change in meaning, which is unavoidable, because it was a restricting relative clause):

> I don't want to do anything. You think **this** might be good for me.

Turning it into a relative clause:

> *<s>I don't want to do anything you think **which** might be good for me.</s>

I chose *which*, because *that* has several different functions, such as a conjunction, which would have made it more confusing. Now we move the relative pronoun to the left:

> I don't want to do anything **which** you think might be good for me.

You can use *which* and *that* almost interchangeably in this example. One feature of *that* is that it can be omitted. You probably learned a rule that *that* can only be omitted when it is object; but, in this case, it is subject, and yet it can still be omitted. The rule should probably be fine-tuned.

If you replace *which* with *that*, you can omit it here, and you arrive at your original sentence.

I don't see any relation between *you think* and the relative pronoun: they don't interact, as far as I can tell, and so the pronoun is not the object of *think*.

Comment: It's not actually nesting but embedding (nesting is something else). In the OP's examples the relativised element is located within an embedded content clause ("might be good for you" / "was good for me".

Comment: @BillJ: We just use different terminology.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Your post is very comprehensive and really has helped me understand more about the construction.

Comment: The construction also reminds me of the sentence **_What you think you know about human evolution is wrong_**. If we interpret **_What_** as **_The thing that_**, does it make **_that_** the object of **_think_**?

Comment: I disagree with you about terminology, but that aside, your statement _You probably learned a rule that that can only be omitted when it is object; but, in this case, it is subject, and yet it can still be admitted. The rule should probably be fine-tuned_ is misleading. The relativised element is indeed a subject, but of the embedded content clause, "might be good for me", not of the relative clause itself, so the rule holds true.

Comment: @BillJ: A relative pronoun can only be object or subject to one verb. "The rule holds true": that depends on how, exactly, you define the rule. The rule as defined above applies but does not hold true. I think what you are saying is that the rule should be fine-tuned or redefined to say something other than the above? How would you define it?

Comment: @Sam: I would say *that* becomes the object of the verb *know*, in the internal clause *you think you know [something] about human evolution*; *something* is replaced with the relative pronoun, which is then moved to the beginning of the full relative clause, *that you think you know [] about human evolution*. The reason that it needs to go so far back is that you cannot move the nested clause *you know [something]* out of the clause that is is a constituent of: it is the object of *think*. So all of that together becomes the relative clause, even though the relative pronoun is nested inside.

Comment: @Sam: You can click the tick mark next to an answer to make it the 'accepted' answer.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Sure. But there's one last thing I want to make sure of, **_The reason that it needs to go so far back..._**, does **_it_** here represent the clause **_you know about human evolution_**?

Comment: @Sam: The thing that needs to go so far back is the thing that is moved, i.e. the relative pronoun. The clauses themselves don't move otherwise.

Comment: @Cerberus_Reinstate_Monica Hi, it's been a while since the topic was solved. I recently discovered a sentence with similar construction but also there's a part of the sentence I don't understand.  Are you willing to help me with this one? Or, do you suggest I create a new topic about it? Thanks.

Comment: @Sam: I suggest that you create a new question. You can put a link to the question here.

Comment: @BillJ The controversy of this thread is that the relative clause in both of the original  sentences still doesn't have the subjective relativizied element. It is the embedded content clause that has the relativized element acting as its subject. So technically they are ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I don't want to do anything you think* [ ___ *might be good for me*].
>
> [2] *This is something he said* [ ___ *was good for me*].

No, it can't be both subject and object simultaneously.

Your examples are both non-*WH* relatives, and since the subordinator "that" is omitted, they are sometimes called 'bare' relatives.

In both cases the missing relativised element (which we can call 'R') is not object but is located within a content clause inside the relative clause, where it is functioning as a subject. The ___ notation indicates the covert presence of the R element.

In [1] R is subject of the embedded "might" clause functioning as complement of "think", and has "anything" as antecedent. We understand that anything might be good for me.

In [2] R is subject of the embedded "was" clause functioning as complement of "said" and has "something" as antecedent. We understand that "something" was good for me

Comment: Are you suggesting the said 'R' element is not a relative pronoun?

Comment: @Sam Because gap is always used to mark the **functional position** of the missing relativised element, which in your examples is subject of an embedded content clause. You have to relealise that relative clauses are the most complex of all finite subordinate clauses, and the embedding of a content clause within a relative clause makes things even more tricky to analyse.

Comment: @Sam Even in a more elementary relative clause where there is a relative pronoun present, ___ is still used to mark the function position of R if it is not the subject of the relative clause, e.g. "This is the book which she recommended ___", where ___ marks the functional position of R (i.e. object of "recommended"), which has "book" as antecedent.

Comment: I was re-reviewing this topic. I noticed I hadn't asked you two important questions: What is the terminology of omitting a relative pronoun functioning as a subject? And, is it grammatically wrong if we put a relative pronoun in the position of the __ notation in either of my sentences?

Comment: Do you mean in the relative clause itself or in the embedded content clause?

Comment: I mean in the embedded content clauses, which are  [ ___ might be good for me] and [ ___ was good for me].

Comment: There's no special name for it. We simply say that the subject or object of the embedded clause is represented by the gap notation '____', where gap is anaphoric to some antecedent -- in your examples the antecedents are "anything" and "something". The embedded content clause is not a relative clause so it cannot be introduced by a relative pronoun.

Comment: No, I said that in "This is the book which she recommended ___",  gap represents the **functional** position of the R element, i.e. object of "recommended". In your last example, there is no relative pronoun ("that" is a subordinator), so gap is again used to indicate the covert presence of the R element, in this case subject.

Answer (score 0):

The relativiser “that” has been omitted in both examples – this is quite usual.

Wikipedia explains “relativser” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativizer

> In linguistics, a relativizer (abbreviated relz) is a type of conjunction that introduces a relative clause. For example, in English, the conjunction that may be considered a relativizer in a sentence such as "I have one that you can use."

In *I don't want to do {anything [that] you think might be good for me}*, *{anything [that] you think might be good for me}* is the object of “don't want to do”

*[that] you think might be good for me* modifies “anything”

Likewise, in *This is {something [that] he said was good for me}*,{something [that] he said was good for me.} is the complement of **This**.

*[that] he said was good for me* modifies “something”.

In both cases it is possible to say that the "he said" and "you think" can

(a) be omitted

(b) create a new clause in which "*[that] he said was good for me*" and *[that] you think might be good for me* are content clauses, i.e. describing the contents of what was said/thought.

This makes no difference to the overall structure.