# Another case of who or whom confusion

Tags: whom, who

The sentence is “she understands who amongst their trio is tasked with protecting everything.” Should it be “whom” because the person is receiving the task of protecting, or “who” because they do the action of protecting?

Thank you.

Comment: Let me answer a question with a question. Would you say "She understands *he* is tasked with protecting everything," or "She understands *him* is tasked with protecting everything"?

Comment: He = who, I take it? This trick works even though it changes the sentence to test the theory?

Comment: Yes, it's *who* that you need here. I think the trick works. I tried not to change the sentence too much.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: The point is that the subject of the subordinate interrogative clause "who amongst their trio is tasked with protecting everything" is the NP "who amongst their trio", the subject of which is a personal pronoun. Subject personal pronouns take nominative case, thus "who" is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What rules make “Remember me, who am your friend” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28662/what-rules-make-remember-me-who-am-your-friend-grammatical) where the more obvious example 'I don't know who did that.' is given '(nominative because even though 'who' is the object of 'know', it is the subject of 'did' and it is loyal to the relative clause)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't relevant who is "receiving" or "doing" an action. What matters is the syntactic role that the noun phrase "who amongst their trio" plays in the interrogative clause "who amongst their trio is tasked with protecting everything." In this case, we see that "who amongst their trio" is the subject of that clause; it plays the same role that "He" does in "He is tasked with protecting everything." Since it is the subject, only *who* would make sense; using *whom* here would be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for this concise answer. You are a very helpful raccoon.

Comment: @PandaSniffles - a raccoon whose helpfulness could be acknowledged even further by you accepting the answer. (You can do that by clicking the checkmark.)

Comment: @Heartspring Consider it done, advocate of the raccoon!